# Не работает parent().height в Mozilla

Tags: jquery, frontend, firefox

Задана функция, которая считает высоту и получает некое значениe X. Далее мы это значение присваиваем изображению и его родителю:

```
  $(this).height(X);
  $(this).parent().height(X);
```

Функция успешно работает во всех браузерах, кроме Mozilla. В Mozilla изображению присваивается высота X, а его родителю - нет. Запускается функция по load. Этой функцией мы переопределяем стандартные настройки слайдера. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Из консоли после того как явно все прогрузилось height работает? На моей практике load с изображениями не очень корректно дружит.

Comment: Нет, сейчас проверяю, оказывается, весь блок после load не отрабатывает. Как тогда быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По непонятной причине дело было в обращении к элементу. Селектор .ms-wk .ms-slide .ms-slide-bgcont .ms-partialview-img срабатывал во всех браузерах, кроме Mozilla. Обычное обращение .ms-partialview-img сработало в Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо стандартной функции `load` воспользуйтесь библиотекой http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: Invision, будет здорово, если вы кратко объясните, почему нужно использовать эту библиотеку и дадите пример использования. Без этого ответ выглядит неполным.

Comment: все необходимые примеры есть по ссылке, рекомендую т.к сам сталкивался с подобной задачей и воспользовался данной библиотекой. За счет различных callback функций достаточно гибкая, может определить когда все изображения в контейнере загружены (в отличии от стандартной функции load).